# what triggers extend non manifold errors?

Tags: vertices

after highlighting my entire mesh, if i click any of the other options and not that one, nothing lights up as non-manifold, but as soon as I click "extend" as active, the entire mesh comes up as non-manifold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting [Non-Manifold](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html#mesh-select-non-manifold) parts of your mesh, will select vertices or edges that are not part of a solid shape.

The **extend** option will add the chosen verts/edges to the current selection. As you have selected all before doing the search, this will just keep everything selected while turning it off will select only non-manifold edges, which could mean no selection.